# Can I use white spaces in the name attribute of an HTML element?

Tags: html

A question has rised in my project team as we are designing a web page.
Can we use white characters (like space) in the name attribute of an HTML element ? eg. `<input type="checkbox" name="first check box">`

My concern is mainly the behavior of different browsers with such an attribute value.

We are now in the design phase, until we get to write some code and test this, a long time will pass, so I am asking you experts about this.

Thank you !

Comment: You can write code while designing.

Comment: Why would you have to wait a long time to test this?

Comment: Worth checking out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/114029

Answer (score 47):

Yes.

The [name attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-name-INPUT) contains [CDATA](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-cdata). It can be more or less anything you like. (You shouldn't include leading or tailing white space because user agents can ignore it, but white space in the middle is fine).

Note that `name` attributes do not have NAME tokens as their data type (although the `id` attribute does (the `id` attribute doesn't take an ID token)), so you don't have the restrictions imposed on NAME tokens.

Comment: +1 @David is correct as pointed out by @preinheimer: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html `name CDATA #IMPLIED -- name of form for scripting` Learned something, thanks.

Comment: Yup. "CDATA is a sequence of characters from the document character set and may include character entities."

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers will handle this fine, as long as they are properly quoted.  However, for sake of eliminating corner cases, it's much wiser to user CamelCase and avoid the probability of browsers not handling it correctly.

Comment: What browser fails to handle it correctly? (I prefer to avoid hacking around unconfirmed bugs in unspecified browsers when the spec says what I want to do is fine)