# PHP Auto-Check checkbox not working

Tags: php, checkbox, space

I have an automatic check system that is not working properly

```
while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($tabela))
{
    $nome = $linha['TABLE_NAME'];

    ?>

        <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $nome ?>" id="<?php echo $nome ?>" value="<?php echo $nome ?>" <?php if(isset($_POST[$nome]))  echo "checked='checked'";?>/> <?php echo $nome ?><br />

    <?php
}
```

The problem is the $nome variable, it have spaces, like 'A B' or '106 South', doing  the system not works correctly... I don't know how to solve it, any help will be welcome!

Comment: Var_dump($nome) please..

Comment: var_dump($nome) returned it > string(7) "106 Sul"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies with the fact that you're using spaces in the `name` attribute of the `input` tag. See [this reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

[This has also been addressed in other SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5688200/1188035)

Spaces are **not allowed** and will not work properly when you submit them using either `POST` or `GET` methods. You should therefore rename any values with spaces or use a `str_replace` function to substitute the spaces with underscores or something similar. Also note the part that said "must begin with a letter"... this also means that a value of `106 Sul` is *invalid* even if you changed it to `106Sul`.

Answer (score 0):

if the space is the problem, cant you just replace it with another character, like this:

```
str_replace(' ','|',$nome);
```

Then when reading the results, you just replace the | with the space and save it to the DB

Comment: Thank you my friend, first time I see this function

Answer (score -1):

You can check an input only with the "checked" value in the tag:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked />
```

Try to write the word instead of "checked='checked'" in your html from php.

Comment: -1 because `checked="checked"` is still valid HTML markup even though it is not common for HTML5, it is alive and kicking for XHTML standards. It will work in any modern browser either way.

Comment: I didn't mention you can't use it.

Comment: However it won't solve the problem, and thus isn't an answer but should rather be a comment.